# Extract more than one attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to extract all the attachements from an email, from a shared mail box, it can be variable (sometimes one sometimes more than one but always PDF).

It only downloads the first one.

Also I have another script that classifies the email in subfolder. I’m using the `mailitem.move` method, and it only moves half by half the email. Is this a limitation from Outlook or VBA?

My script for extracting attachments.

```vb
Sub ExtrairePJ_Mail()
    'Déclaration des variables.
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Namespace
    Dim NameFile As String
    
    
    ' variables liées à Outlook.
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Diffusion")
    Set mydestFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("director")
    'Set pj = Outlook.
    'Variable modiafiable.
    n = 1 'Numéro en cas d'existance de fichier.
    FolderPath = "path"  'Chemin du dossier où l'on souhaite sauvegarder le fichier
    'NameFile = oMail.Attachments.Item(1).Filename & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf" 'Nom du fichier format : Nom de la piece jointe-mm-dd-yyyy.pdf
    
    'Boucle parcourant la boite mail
    For Each oMail In myFolder.Items
        'Condition vérifiant si l'objet est "AUD_ACTTER Reports the active terminals of users who did not sign off properly"
        'If oMail.subject Like "*" & "AUD_ACTTER Reports the active terminals of users who did not sign off properly" & "*" Then
        
        If oMail.subject Like "*" & "test2pj" & "*" Then
            Debug.Print oMail.subject & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "-" & n
            
            oMail.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile FolderPath & oMail.Attachments.Item(1).Filename & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf"

            Set pj = Nothing
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next oMail    
End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru It is now working, i've forget tu change ONE variable in the saveas focntion ... Thanks you a lot have a really nice day you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try changing of this code part:

```
  If oMail.subject Like "*" & "test2pj" & "*" Then
            Debug.Print oMail.subject & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "-" & n
            
            oMail.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile FolderPath & oMail.Attachments.Item(1).Filename & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf"

            Set pj = Nothing
            n = n + 1
  End If
```

with this one:

```
  Dim strName As String
  Dim oAtach As Attachment 'put this line somewhere to the code beginning
  If oMail.subject Like "*" & "test2pj" & "*" Then
        'Debug.Print oMail.subject & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "-" & n
            
        For Each oAtach In oMail.Attachments
            strName = Split(oAtach.DisplayName, ".")(0)
            If Dir(folderPath & strName & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf") = "" Then
                oAtach.SaveAsFile folderPath & strName & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf"
            Else
                oAtach.SaveAsFile folderPath & strName & "-" & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy") & n & ".pdf"
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
        Set pj = Nothing
  End If
```

Comment: Hello, thanks you for the answer, i've understant your solution but how does it parse all the email from outlook,
Do i need to do it in two loop ?
like so: 
```
 For Each oMail In myFolder.Items
        For Each oAtach In oMail.Attachments
```??

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: I cannot get you, sorry... Your code already iterates between `myFolder.Items`. The suggested solution does what is to be done for **all** `oMail` objects. Did ou try it?

Comment: Soory my bad I didn't understood the first time i've read it, I've tried your solution and still doesn't working it keep extracting the first attachement.

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: This should not be possible... Are you sure that the mail(s) in discussion do not have only one attachment? Or, are there identic names in different mails? In such a case the existing saved attachments are overwritten.  In this case, you should move the `n` variable incrementing line inside the new loop. I thought that you need the `n` to be unique per mail, not per attachment. In fact, I will adapt the code as I just said... Did it. Please, test the updated code.

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: do you have any news? Did you test it as it is now? Does it still not return what you need?

Comment: It's working thanks you! i have now another issue, the struture of my namefile should be like this : Name_YYYY_MM_DD
and if the file already exist in my folder, it add a number after the DD so it should looks like this Name_YYYY_MM_DD_1 do you have any suggestion to do it ?

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: What "Name" should mean? The attachment name? If yes, the name including the extension? If not, what does it mean? But I must emphasize that it is another question. Do you appreciate that my answer did not answer your question as it is?

Comment: Format of the Name file : Filename_Timestamp.pdf
if file already exist in folder 
Filename_timesptamp_N.pdf
N is an incremental variable

Comment: So, the "Name" should be the attachment name. Is this understanding correct? If yes, should it contain the file extension? And you avoided to answer the last question "Do you appreciate that my answer did not answer your question as it is?... What would you answer?

Comment: Yes, i'm extracting the attachement by juste adding the timestamp between the extension and the name of the attachement
and yes i appreciate your answer, my question was not clear enough.
maybe should we move to a different platforme to continue to discuss ? like by email.

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: No need of any discussion, I think. I will leave my office in some minutes. Please, test the updated code. I would also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If somebody else searches for a similar issue, he will know that the code works. The main purpose is to make people learning! And, if a question has been answered, you do what I said before and **place another question**. Otherwise, we risk spending hours to answer a never ending question. It is a matter of principle..

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: Please, take care: I added a new variable, too `Dim strName As String`...

Comment: Ok thanks you for all the answers !! i'm new at this forum i didn't knew the way it works:) i'll check the boxes Have a really nice Day !!

Comment: @Melvin ceylan: OK, that was a different way to learn something... Now, did the updated code do what you need?

Comment: no it did not, i'll make à specific topic for this issue :)

Comment: OK it works, again i forget to change a little something '-'... Thanks you @FaneDuru